# Query values in IEnumerable<Claims> for access token

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, ienumerable, access-token

I am trying to query the value of app id within `IEnumerable<Claims>`. By using Linq, I am not able to use `select` or `where` statement as `x => x.appid` is not present. 
[image]

Here's the code:

```
var tokenS = jwtHandler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
var appId = tokenS.Claims.Where(x => x.key == "appid").ToString();
```

But `key` does exist. Anyone knows how to get the `appid` value properly using linq?

Comment: @JohanP it says "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'claim'" and token.Claim is of 
 type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim> {System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Security.Claims.Claim>}
`

Comment: Ok, how does the `Claim` class look like?

Comment: this is what it looks like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claim?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `.Where(x => x.Type == "appid")`

Comment: this is not a valid lambda expression for `.Where()`, as lambda expressions passed to `Where()` are supposed to return booleans.

Comment: thanks. this worked `tokenS.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "appid").FirstOrDefault().Value`

Comment: @WWpana you can omit `.Where` when doing `.FirstOrDefault()` i.e. `tokenS.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "appid")?.Value`